# Android WebView zooms after click on a link (while loading new page) on HD phones

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have an Android application that uses Cordova and WebView to display content loaded from remote web server (mostly static pages generated by PHP/Zend).

Zooming of web content is disabled by all methods I know about (since PHP generates layout based on resolution send by the App), but on HD phones (320/480DPI; e.g. Samsuns S3/Note, HTC one, etc.) **when a user clicks a link to load new page, the content of the old page is zoomed in** while the WebView waits for response from the server (less than 1s but still looks annoying).

Viewport is set to device resolution w/o zooming:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

or as defined in Zend:

```
$view->headMeta()->appendName('viewport', 'initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi');
```

Zooming is also disabled for WebView (in InitialActivity of the APK):

```
appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
```

*There are also several JS libraries (google-analytics, jQuery 1.9.1, jQuery UI, Photoswipe for jQuery 3.0.5) so I'm no sure if any of them could be causing this.*

Any tips what could be causing this?

PS: As the final solution I'm thinking about hiding the content of the page in onUnload handler, but I would like to know why I have to do such radical things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No aswer yet, so I will at least post how I've solved the problem (in case someone happens to have similar one).

```
/**
 * disables default link redirect; shows splash screen and redirects after few milliseconds
 *
 * @param  event {Event/String} either event from user action (then 'this' must be an anchor <A>) or URL for manual redirect
 */
linkRedirect = function(event) {
    var
        curHref = document.location.href,
        newHref = this.href;

    if ('string' === typeof event) {
        newHref = event;
        event = null;
    }

    if ('string' === typeof newHref && !newHref.match('^mailto:')) {
        (event && event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : undefined); //stop default browser link redirect

        curHref = curHref.split('#');  //separate URL path (part that is send to server) and hash (part only for browser)
        newHref = newHref.split('#');

        if ('' !== newHref[0] && curHref[0] !== newHref[0]) { //new URL has different server path - redirect (if newHref[0] is empty, it means on Hash was passed)
            navigator.splashscreen.show(); //show splash
            $('body').height();   //force browser to update DOM by reading a CSS property

            mv.user.redirectTo.defer(100, this, [newHref.join('#')]); //allow the DOM to redraw and then redirect
        }
        else if (newHref[1] && curHref[1] !== newHref[1]) { //new URL has different only the hash - change it (link <a href="#"> is reserver for onclick handler and is ignored!!!)
            document.location.hash = newHref[1];
        }
    } //else no HREF on this link - ignore it
};

/**
 * Loads page from given URL into current document
 *
 * @param  link {String}
 */
redirectTo = function(link) {
    document.location.href = link;
};

/**
 * Disable default form submission; shows splash screen and submits data after few milliseconds
 *
 * @param  event {Event} event for user action
 * @return {Boolean} returns false to prevent default submission
 */
formSubmit = function(event) {
    (event && event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : undefined);
    navigator.splashscreen.show(); //show splash
    $('body').height();   //force browser to update DOM by reading a CSS property

    $('<form>')[0].submit.defer(100, this); //allow the DOM to redraw and then redirect
    /* form.submit should be a method to submit the form, but in case some form element (usually the submit button)
     * has ID="submit", then form.submit contains reference to the element (button) and there is no way to manually
     * submit the button (and form.submit.click() cannot be used as it would only create recursion).
     *
     * Workaround is to create new empty Form and use its submit method called on the correct scope.
     */

    return false; //same as prevent default (for case event is missing)
};

$(document).on('click', 'a', linkRedirect); //watch for clicks on links and hide page content before redirect
$(document).on('submit', 'form', formSubmit); //watch for form submissions and hide page content before submitting
```